# WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a website running on Windows Server 2008 with MS SQL Server 2008 Web Edition.

I want to host a blog, tightly coupled to the site, and after reading a good few articles, decided that I would like to install WP in a folder off the website root, accessible like this?

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog
```

I've just upgraded to Web Platform 4.6, and this has returned a few different options with regard to installation. Here's what I have:

- Standard WordPress installation
- Brandoo WordPress
- WebMatrix3

WordPress itself is not familiar (apart from using it of course), and wondered if anyone could shed any light on these options.

Comment: Are you wanting to run Wordpress with an MS SQL Server database?

Comment: That's entirely possible as we already have MS SQL installed, however the standard wordpress installation says that MySQL is used. I can't think of any reasons that I'd choose to install MySQL if MS SQL is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Brandoo Wordpress uses MS SQL or Azure SQL by default. If You want to install WordPress winth thos DB's, use Brandoo WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/getting-started) and [here](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server). Since this is essentially a fork of Wordpress, security updates and whatnot may be delayed. To use the official Wordpress code, you'll have to install MySQL.